# How do I run batch scripts from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I'm having a bit of a problem trying to write a PowerShell script that allows me to open up `cmd.exe` and then write into it so I can run some batch scripts. I'm building this to be able to work with `octo.exe` in case that helps any for working with releases.

So far I have:

```
cmd.exe /c start cmd
```

I've tried a few different things, and everything I find online is for opening and running PowerShell from `cmd.exe`.

Comment: why not use powershell to create a bat file with the commands you need to run then execute the bat file with cmd.exe

Comment: You can run external commands directly from PowerShell.

Comment: PowerShell is, as the name implies, a Shell that should perform pretty much any action that you would use cmd.exe (which is also a shell) to perform. Why do you feel that you need to launch cmd.exe, and be able to write to it?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician The only reason why I would be writing to cmd.exe is because I already have a script to run my release using octo.exe within cmd.exe. I'm not proficient with powershell and in fact this is basically my first time using it other than modifying portions of previously provided script.

Comment: Consider this an opportunity to improve your knowledge.

Comment: You can use VBScript's or .NET's SendKeys functions to send arbitrary text to currently focused window. You should be able to open a new CMD window from PowerShell and cause it to come into focus. Throw a timer in between to be safe and there you go.

Comment: On second thought: Don't use `SendKeys`. ***Ever.***

Comment: you can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417196/execute-batch-file-in-powershell

Answer (score 6):

You can run batch scripts in PowerShell, just like in cmd.exe. No need for you to call cmd.exe.

```
myOctoScript.bat
```

If the path to the script is a string, or stored in a string, use the `&` operator to tell PowerShell to treat the string as a command:

```
& $pathToOctoBatchScript
& 'Path\To\Octo\Batch\Script.bat'
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip @Aaron

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\PathToBatFile\FileToExecute.bat" -ArgumentList $argstr -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

*Here,*

**ArgumentList** - to pass parameters or parameter values if needed by bat file

**Wait** - waits for the process(bat) to complete

**NoNewWindow** - starts the new process in the current console window.