# Execute batch file in Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to execute the following from a batch file:

```
"C:\OpenCover\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe" -register:user -target:"%VS110COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\mstest.exe" -targetargs:"/testcontainer:\"C:\Develop\bin\Debug\MyUnitTests.dll\" ... "
PAUSE
```

Now I would like to log the output of the process to a file for which I came across the quite handy powershell usage of

```
powershell "dir | tee output.log"
```

but this does not take my batch file as first argument (`powershell "my.bat | tee output.log"`) because it is not the name of a cmdlet or a function or a script file.

I could change my batch file so that is says `powershell "OpenCover.Console.exe..."` but I would have to adapt all quotes and change escape characters and so forth.

Is there a way to make a batch file execute in powershell? Or is there a way to drop in my line unchanged from the batch after some powershell command and it all executes "like it ought to"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless your batch file is in a folder in the `%PATH%`, PowerShell won't find it <sup>[1]</sup>, so you'll have to supply an explicit file path (whether relative or absolute).

For instance, if the batch file is in the current folder, run:

```
powershell -c ".\my.bat | tee output.log"
```

<sup>Consider adding `-noprofile` to suppress loading of the profile files, which is typically only needed in *interactive* sessions.</sup>

If your batch file path contains embedded spaces, enclose it in single quotes and prepend `&`:

```
powershell -c "& '.\my script.bat' | tee output.log"
```

Note: I've deliberately added the `-c` (short for: `-Command`) parameter name above; while `powershell.exe` - *Windows PowerShell* - defaults to this parameter, that is no longer true in *PowerShell [Core] v6+* (whose executable name is `pwsh`), where `-File` is now the default - see [`about_PowerShell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PowerShell.exe) and [`about_pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh)

---

<sup>[1] More accurately, PowerShell - unlike `cmd.exe` - will *by design* not execute scripts in the *current* folder by their mere filename (in an interactive PowerShell session you'll get a hint to that effect). This is a security feature designed to prevent accidental invocation of a different executable than intended.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some purpose for doing so not stated in the OP, there isn't a reason to use both Powershell and a batch script. If you want to do this solely from PS, you can create a PS script that does everything the batch file does.

To avoid the escaping issues (or alternatively to take advantage of CMD.EXE's somewhat strange escaping behavior :-) you can use `--%`, introduced in PS 3.0. It is documented under about_escape_characters.